# Laravel login authentication without authorization command

Tags: laravel

Can someone please tell me how to compare the posted/input value with database value for login authentication in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

To compare a password with user.password column you must to use \Hash::check() method.

First parameter is plain password and second is the hashed password from database.

Answer (score 0):

you can use @renan.wao method or you can also use the attampt method to authenticate a user like below.

```
public function verify(Request $request)
    {
 $credential=Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]);
        if($credential)
        {
           return redirect('home');
        else
        {
            return back()->with('msg', 'Error!Enter Cedentials Correctly');
        }
    }
```